# How can I check my static library attached to the executable file?

Tags: c, linux, static-libraries

I create statlic library `lib.a` and I compile it with my program using that command:

```
gcc -o main main.o -L. lib.a
```

Everythink working correctly but, how I can check that mine `main` using `lib.a`? I thought I should use `ldd` command but, this command is only for dynamic libraries. Is any command to check it ?

Comment: An executable file doesn't need a static library "next" to it. The library code is already "embedded" into the executable code. I'm guessing that I've misread your question in some manner, but at least by the title, this seems like a "reasonable" interpretation.

Comment: There is no need for a library if your code is statically linked. The executable will be a standalone. Or I am wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate a linker map file with following option

`Xlinker -Map=output.map` to see the used objects from your library